# keeping image center after changing height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a simple page that opens an image with a few styles. However, when I change the height to say...  height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 200, the image gets smaller but does not remain center. Also, it might even be cutting out the image. How can I fix this so I can make the image smaller but remain center?

If I give it a height: 100 and a width: 100, and position it with absolute or justify content, will it look the same across all devices?

Thank you guys for any input at all! I appreciate it more than you know.

```
import React from'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions, Image, Animated} from 'react-native'

const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height
const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width

const Bars = [
  {id : "1", uri: require('./assets/placeholder1.jpg')},
  {id : "2", uri: require('./assets/placeholder2.jpg')},
  {id : "3", uri: require('./assets/placeholder3.jpg')},
  {id : "4", uri: require('./assets/placeholder4.jpg')},
  {id : "5", uri: require('./assets/placeholder5.jpg')},
  {id : "6", uri: require('./assets/placeholder6.jpg')},
  {id : "7", uri: require('./assets/placeholder7.jpg')},
  {id : "8", uri: require('./assets/placeholder8.jpg')},
  {id : "9", uri: require('./assets/placeholder9.jpg')},
]

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
         
         {/* styles header */}
         <View style={{height: 60 }}>

         </View>

         {/* styles bar images */}
         <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Animated.View style={styles.barImage}>

                <Image 
                style={{flex: 1 ,
                        height: null,
                        width: null,
                        
                        borderRadius: 20
                      }}
                resizeMode='cover'
                source={Bars[0].uri} />
                
             </Animated.View>
         </View>

          {/* styles footer if I even need it */}
         <View style={{height: 60 }}>

         </View>

      </View>
    )
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  barImage: {
    height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 170, 
    width:SCREEN_WIDTH, 
    padding: 10,
  
    }
  }
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `resizeMode` wrong. `resizeMode` is a prop of the `<Image />` component. You have to wrap the `<Image />` with a `<View />` and give that `<View />` a `width` and `height` and center that `<View />`.

```
<View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
    <View style={{width: 100, height: 100}}>
        <Image 
            ...
            resizeMode='cover'
            ...
        />
    </View>
</View>
```

Comment: So what should I do instead?

Comment: Did you try setting `resizeMode` to `cover` on the `<Image />` component and not it's style?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, I have updated my code, still no luck.

Comment: I just need to make the picture smaller but that it looks the same universally across all devices.

Comment: Okay awesome! Thank you, and these sizes will remain the same look regardless of device size?

Comment: The whole reason I used the device height and width was so it will look the same regardless of what device you are using

Comment: I wouldn't advice to use device height and width cos two devices might not have the same height and width, so the image won't look the same.

Answer (score 1):

In your stylesheet, use the margin elements to center the image. If you set them to auto, it'll center them automatically. You can also use vertical-align and many other center components. Use this website for more context and better understanding with multiple other ways to suit your use case : https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html